# How do I push review objects into an existing model's array using Angular and a form?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, forms

First off, I am very new to Angular, and working on my first real MEAN app.

I am building an app that allows users to leave reviews on surf spots. I already have a model for surf spots, and each surf spot has an array that is supposed to hold reviews.

I'm not sure how I can go about using a form to add a review into the array for that spot.  Do I need to create a Schema for the reviews?  Do I need to create another controller and service for reviews in order to add them to my spots?

I know this is a pretty broad question, but I could really use some direction if anyone can offer it.

Spot Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var SpotSchema = new Schema({
  name      : String,
  location  : String,
  reviews   : Array,
  latitude  : Number,
  longitude : Number,
  tide      : String,
  rating    : Number,
  region    : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Spot", SpotSchema);
```

Spot Controller:

```
angular.module("spotCtrl", ["spotService"])

.controller("spotController", function(Spot) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.processing = true;

  Spot.all()
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.processing = false;
      vm.spots = data;
    });
})

.controller("singleSpotController", function($routeParams, Spot) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.processing = true;

  Spot.get($routeParams.spot_id)
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.processing = false;
      vm.spotData = data;
    })
})
```

Spot Service:

```
angular.module("spotService", [])

.factory("Spot", function($http) {
  var spotFactory = {};

  spotFactory.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get("/api/spots/" + id);
  };

  spotFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get("/api/spots/");
  };

  return spotFactory;
});
```

Finally, the view that displays the data for a single Spot. This is where the form needs to go, but I'm not sure how I can use a form to create a review object, and then push it into the array for that spot.

Spot View:

```
<div ng-model="singleSpot.spotData">

  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="single-spot">
      {{ singleSpot.spotData.name }} <br>
      {{ singleSpot.spotData.location }} <br>
      Rating: {{ singleSpot.spotData.rating }} <br>
      Current Tide: {{ singleSpot.spotData.tide }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <form>
    <!-- What do I do here? -->
  </form>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want a spot to have multiple reviews.

```
var SpotSchema = new Schema({
  name      : String,
  location  : String,
  reviews   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}],
  latitude  : Number,
  longitude : Number,
  tide      : String,
  rating    : Number,
  region    : String
});
```

Then create a new schema for your reviews

```
var ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  review: String,
  _Spot: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Spot'},
  created_at: Date
});
```

Inside your Html

```
<div ng-controller="reviewController"
  <form>
      <textarea name="review" ng-model="new_review"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="addReview(singlespot.SpotData)">
  </form>
</div>
```

Then create your reviewController and factory and send the data to the Db as you are already doing. Note you have passed the singlespot.SpotData along with ur addReview so you can repack it and use it to findOne spot and then push the review inside the spot.reviews

your backend will look something like this

```
Spot.findOne({_id: req.body.spot_id}, function (err, spot){
            var review = new Review(req.body);
            review._Spot = Spot._id;
            spot.reviews.push(review);
            review.save(function(err){
            spot.save(function(err){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Error"); 
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Succesfully added Review");
                }
            });
            });
        });
```

basically you have to find your spot then push the review into the spot.reviews and save the review as well.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you elaborate on what exactly is happening in the lines:  
  
    ```reviews   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}]```
  
and  
  
    ``` _Spot: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Spot'}```

Comment: reviews : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}]

in the above line we are creating a one to many relationship between spot and reviews, the reviews being an array inside the spot schema.

It has 2 properties, type & ref. The type is a unique identifier for our association which will be the ObjectId of each review. And the ref is reference to which model the unique identifier is associated with.

_Spot: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Spot'

this line we are telling the review model it belongs to the spot model.